# using hashlib to create a sha512 password

Tags: hash, salt, sha512, hashlib

I'm following some python book and the author provides an example of using crypt to produce a hashed password. Using the salt+password; and later he mentioned that the same could be done for sha512 using hashlib library. So I tried to use
 `hashlib.sha512(password+salt).hexdigest()` 
to see if I could come up with my same password in the /etc/shadow file, but I'm not getting anything remotely similar. I'm using the salt that shows as part of my password hash. Am I doing it correctly, or that salt needs to be in ascii form? Also does the salt goes first and then the password like hashlib.sha512(salt+password).hexdigest()? the rest of my code is pretty simple. It is that part about finding the salt, and hashing it properly.  `nagios:$6$P9zn0KwR$tgfvvFWJJ5FKmoXiP5rXWOjwoEBOEoAuBi3EphRbJqqjWYvhEM2wa67L9XgQ7W591FxUNklkDIQsk4kij uhE50:16632:0:99999:7:::`

for example the salt I'm using is "P9zn0KwR" is this correct or I need to find the clear text for that salt... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using hash algorithms like MD5 or SHA-* is an unsecure way to store passwords, because they are ways too fast and therefore can be brute-forced too easily.

Have a look at the [Phyton docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html#key-derivation), the part about key stretching. It seems that they implemented the PBKDF2 for passwords which is recommended. The [passlib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/passlib/) seems to be a good choice too, they support the BCrypt algorithm.